# Unity: How to zoom out of camera and place cam between 2 objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

using Unity 2018.3 2D

I have a camera using the Orthigraphic projection and my default size is 6-8 but I would like to at button click to zoom out the size of the camera to be within 2 objects, first object to be all the way to the left of the screen and the 2nd object all the way to the right. The size of the camera now would be around 20-30.

I know how to move the cameras transform but how would I calculate the distance between 2 objects then zoom out the size so the 2 objects are at the corner of the screen.

How to do it? I would first get which 2 objects will be the left and right then calculate the Vector2 distance to then get a camera size number so both objects are within?? is that one way to do it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are working in 2D. In my opinion, with ortographic map in order to zoom you just have to relocalize the camera to the center of the objects and adjust the `orthographicSize` like this for example:

```
    centerPoint = (objectRight.transform.position - objectLeft.transform.position)/2;
    centerPoint.z  = -10;

    CameraSize = (objectRight.transform.position - objectLeft.transform.position).magnitude 
               -objectLeft.transform.localScale.x;

    Camera.main.transform.position = centerPoint;
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = CameraSize / 2;
```

You can also use `Lerp` to make it smooth